# Conversion exceptions while using docx4j (From Docx to PDF)

Tags: pdf-generation, docx4j

I would like to know why this code:

```
      String inputfilepath = "D:\\DFADFADSF";
      WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath + ".docx"));
      MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();            
      wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(new IdentityPlusMapper());
      FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
      foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
      String outputfilepath = "D:\\OUT_FontContent.pdf";
      OutputStream os = new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputfilepath);
      Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage,os);
```

Throws this exception:

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception exporting package
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception executing transformer: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:flow" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+
```

Although there are similar posts, I haven't seen one about this exception...

Maybe I should add aditional code to configure the conversion...

Comment: Can you put the docx causing the error somewhere for download?

Comment: I think there is another post made by me about exactly the same... Anyway... Sorry for no answering me... When I return to the department, I'll think of a way.. Thanx